# Trying to blink LED STM32Cube IDE STM32F411E-DISCO

Tags: c, embedded, stm32f4discovery, stm32cubeide

I'm trying to get started with STM32Cube IDE by blinking an LED on the board (PD15). I generated the starter C code by selecting the correct board, then added the following to the main loop:

```
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15);
  HAL_Delay(200);
```

I know the board works because I can run the example code "Demonstrations" which uses all of the LEDs, unfortunately the source isn't provided. I think the problem might be with the auto generated code so here is the full code:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_host.h"

void SystemClock_Config(void);

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  }
}



/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing? That the LED does not blink, the incorrect LED blinks, etc?

Comment: If you are just trying to get the LED blinking do you need to have the I2C, I2S, SPI, and USB peripherals and code active? Even just for testing, can you remove them and simplify your code? Also do you know that your code is running in the main loop? Have you checked with a debugger that the MCU is not stuck in the Error_Handler() loop, or an empty ISR?

Comment: The LED does not blink at all. Also I'm not using the peripherals so I've now removed most of that code. Before and after removing the code however I am getting stuck in the Error_Handler loop, this is the error that appears in the debuggeer console: "set *(int *)0xE000EDFC=*(int *)0xE000EDFC|0x7F0" @tinman

Comment: Update:  After also removing the System Clock configuration code, I no longer get an error and the main loop runs properly, but still the LED does not light up at all

Comment: Your text says "PD15", but the code says `HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12);`, that is at least mildly confusing. Also, I'm not sure I'm seeing GPIO setup code to make that pin an output? If you have update the Cube project to not need all the other peripherals I think you should update the question too to cut out that code.

Comment: The only other thing I can see is that you say you want to toggle PD15 but you use GPIO_PIN_12 in your call to Toggle(). But that should just blink the wrong LED. You should try to get the clock configuration running again, otherwise you don’t know if the timing base for HAL_Delay() is correct. It seems odd that generating the code in CubeMX when starting from the board is wrong. Has this board been used in the past, perhaps someone has reconfigured solder bridges?

Comment: You're right, I was trying the other LEDs in case they worked. I updated the question with what I currently have @unwind

Comment: @unwind the LD6_Pin definition should be  GPIO_PIN_15 based on the evaluation board user manual.

Comment: Your updated code removes the initialisation of the GPIO ports, so you probably won’t get any outputs on the LEDs. You need to keep MX_GPIO_Init().

Comment: Yeah, like @tinman says, you must initialize the proper GPIO port (just port D is enough) so that it is clocked, and you must set the pin as an output so you should still have the GPIO init function but only for this (not for the pin needs of the old peripheral-heavy code).

Comment: Ok I've updated the code with the pin initialization, though I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly. I also changed it to WritePin to remove the need for a clock @tinman

Comment: You need to include the line `__HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();` before trying to initialise port D. Put that in after your call to `HAL_Init()`. This is what @unwind meant by making sure the port is clocked. It enables the clock to the port D peripheral so that the CPU can access its registers.

Comment: The LED toggle fragment does not appear in the "full code" where you simple set the GPIO repeatedly to the same value with no delay.

Answer (score 0):

From the thread on the original post, my problem was that I was not initializing the GPIO ports properly, and the following line was missing from below the `HAL_Init()` line:

```
__HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
```

With the changes I am able to control the LEDs

Comment: I have a bunch of years of experience with the STM32 controllers, but always went straight to the metal and never used Cube's code generation ... I'm a bit surprised; if you specify that you want to use a GPIO pin, shouldn't it emit code to set that up, that you can include?

Comment: It does generate this code, but the code it generated was getting stuck in the error loop. Maybe it's just a bug with this model of board.